# SSL for C# HttpListener on SLES

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, https

I am running a C# .NET HttpListener on SLES and the http connection is working well.
Now https is required.
The problem is that I dont know where to put my SSL Certificates(which I already have) and how to tell the httpListener to use them.
Since I only know how to install ssl with an apache server I dont know where to start and google only knew how to do it for windows.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Use WebSocket instead.  HTTPS uses TLS which uses the SSL option on following : https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.WebSockets.Client/src/System/Net/WebSockets/WebSocketHandle.Managed.cs

Comment: Ok that would be an option. Is there maybe a possibility to do some routing over a apache virtual host to do the ssl stuff and just forward all requests to my httplistener. Implementing everythong with WebSocket seems like a huge effort

Comment: HTTPListener is old (obsolete)and it looks like it doesn't support TLS.  TLS is performed before the request is sent and develops an encryption key to use for the request.